# Viewing dojo source files in IE Developer Toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, ie-developer-tools

I am using dojo toolkit in my website. This is the piece of code I am using to include the dojo library

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var djConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true,
            isDebug: true,
            locale: 'en-us'
        };
    </script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

When I load my web page in IE I see the list of files that were loaded using `dojo.require` as bunch of `anonymous code` in IE developer tool script tag. I am guessing that this is happening because dojo is "injecting" the script files referred by `dojo.require` using xhr calls.

Does anyone know a way to tell IE Developer tools to not load these files as "anonymous code" but to display these source files as regular JavaScript files?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load scripts with cross-domain loader asynchronously, i.e. via inserting script tags into HTML head. There was djConfig attribute debugAtAllCosts for that, but it is broken in Dojo 1.6 and not present in v1.7, because of the transition to AMD loader.

If you are interested to see just Dojo Toolkit files, you can load Dojo asynchronously from Google CDN:

```
<script
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" 
  type="text/javascript"
  data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true, baseUrl: './', modulePaths: {'ego': 'src/ego'}">
</script>
```

Note you can also configure Dojo to load your modules synchronously via XHR by specifying "baseUrl" and "modulePaths" in dojo config.

Other two possibilities are:

1. For Dojo 1.6 and previous do [a xdomain build](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/xDomain.html), which converts all you modules so you can load them with xdomain async loader.
2. Start using Dojo 1.7 and convert your application to AMD (see [The Dojo Loader](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd)).

Comment: Thanks! Would probably move to Dojo 1.7 soon! till then `debugger;` is my friend